# VS Code HTML formatter that preserves inline comments

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find a decent HTML formatter plugin for VS Code that won't "break" a lot of pre-existing HTML that has inline comments e.g.

```
<div>hello</div><!-- class="world" -->
```

Shouldn't turn into this:

```
<div>hello</div>
<!-- class="world" -->
```

Apparently jsbeautify is not good about this. I tried prettier and same issue..the comments would wrap. After a lot of digging I disabled everything but now I don't have basic auto-formatting of html tags to auto-indent etc.

If anyone has a good vs code setup that addresses this, would highly appreciate if you could share which plugin you're using and any associated plugin settings that may be required to preserve inline comment formatting.

Thanks,

- S. Arora

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.json`, add

```
 "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
      },
```

From there, you can search for "whitespace" in the `settings` UI of VSCode, and configure as you like.

Comment: Tried that formatter using it's default configuration but it doesn't work for me. I don't see any relevant whitespace setting so probably I'm missing something that works for you. For now I found a vscode extension called 'HTML Format' that doesn't have a lot of options but does the minimal.